# Update nested table item

Tags: oracle, update

I'm really new on oracle db. I'm trying to update specific column on this table.

```
CREATE TYPE ABSTRACT_SALARY AS OBJECT (
startDate DATE,
endDate DATE,
salary NUMBER );

CREATE TYPE SALARY_TYPE AS TABLE OF ABSTRACT_SALARY;

CREATE TABLE Person(
---
---
---
---
salaryType SALARY_TYPE
)
NESTED TABLE salaryType STORE AS person_salaryTypes;
```

How can I **update salary column** %10 higher. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update all rows in the whole nested table:

```
update /*+ NESTED_TABLE_GET_REFS */ person_salaryTypes
set salary = salary * 1.1;
commit;
```

Update all rows in the nested table for 1 person:

```
update table(select p.salarytype from person p where p.id = 1)
set salary = salary * 1.1;
commit;
```

Update 1 row in the nested table for 1 person:

```
update table(select p.salarytype from person p where p.id = 1)
set salary = salary * 1.1
where startdate = ...;
commit;
```